# Show the overflow of a div that is inside another div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Why is my div cutting off the content of its contained absolutely positioned div?

I am trying to get my twitter bootstrap popover to be "on top" of the containing div. As you can see below, the popover is being cut off.

**Z-index**

Popover is absolutely positioned, so figured I'd try increasing `z-index`. Didn't work.

**overflow: visible**

Then next I figured I'd check for all the containing elements having `overflow` set to something other than `visible`, but that also didn't change anything.

Is there some CSS attribute I'm forgetting to check?

[image: Can I create a Twitter Bootstrap tooltip on an element when it is clicked?]

Comment: Have you assigned Position:relative for your popup div ???

Comment: No the pop-up div is positioned absolutely. The parent div is positioned relatively.

Comment: Can you post your code (CSS) for reference. Or create jsFiddle.

Comment: Sounds like there is an `overflow: hidden` hiding in there somewhere. Demo or it didn't happen.

Comment: Is the parent element having `position: relative`?
Also, try to show some code here!